# How do I extract info deep inside XML using C# and LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This is my first post on StackOverflow, so please bear with me. And I apologize upfront if my code example is a bit long.

Using C# and LINQ, I'm trying to identify a series of third level `id` elements (000049 in this case) in a much larger XML file.  Each third level `id` is unique, and the ones I want are based on a series of descendant info for each.  More specifically, if `type == A` and `location type(old) == vault` and `location type(new) == out`, then I want to select that `id`.  Below is the XML and C# code that I'm using.

In general my code works.  As written below it will return an `id` of 000049 twice, which is correct.  However, I have found a glitch.  If I remove the first `history` block that contains `type == A`, my code still returns an `id` of 000049 twice when it should only return it once.  I know why it is happening, but I can't figure out a better way to run the query.  Is there a better way to run my query to get the output I want and still use LINQ?

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1" ?>
<data type="historylist">
    <date type="runtime">
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>04</month>
        <day>22</day>
        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
        <hour>15</hour>
        <minutes>24</minutes>
        <seconds>46</seconds>
    </date>
    <customer>
        <id>0001</id>
        <description>customer</description>
        <mediatype>
            <id>kit</id>
            <description>customer kit</description>
            <volume>
                <id>000049</id>
                <history>
                    <date type="optime">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                        <hour>03</hour>
                        <minutes>00</minutes>
                        <seconds>02</seconds>
                    </date>
                    <userid>batch</userid>
                    <type>OD</type>
                    <location type="old">
                        <repository>vault</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <location type="new">
                        <repository>out</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <container>0001.kit.000049</container>
                    <date type="movedate">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                    </date>
                </history>
                <history>
                    <date type="optime">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                        <hour>06</hour>
                        <minutes>43</minutes>
                        <seconds>33</seconds>
                    </date>
                    <userid>vaultred</userid>
                    <type>A</type>
                    <location type="old">
                        <repository>vault</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <location type="new">
                        <repository>out</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <container>0001.kit.000049</container>
                    <date type="movedate">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                    </date>
                </history>
                <history>
                    <date type="optime">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                        <hour>06</hour>
                        <minutes>43</minutes>
                        <seconds>33</seconds>
                    </date>
                    <userid>vaultred</userid>
                    <type>S</type>
                    <location type="old">
                        <repository>vault</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <location type="new">
                        <repository>out</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <container>0001.kit.000049</container>
                    <date type="movedate">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                    </date>
                </history>
                <history>
                    <date type="optime">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                        <hour>06</hour>
                        <minutes>45</minutes>
                        <seconds>00</seconds>
                    </date>
                    <userid>batch</userid>
                    <type>O</type>
                    <location type="old">
                        <repository>out</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <location type="new">
                        <repository>site</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <container>0001.kit.000049</container>
                    <date type="movedate">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                    </date>
                </history>
                <history>
                    <date type="optime">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                        <hour>11</hour>
                        <minutes>25</minutes>
                        <seconds>59</seconds>
                    </date>
                    <userid>ihcmdm</userid>
                    <type>A</type>
                    <location type="old">
                        <repository>out</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <location type="new">
                        <repository>site</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <container>0001.kit.000049</container>
                    <date type="movedate">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                    </date>
                </history>
                <history>
                    <date type="optime">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                        <hour>11</hour>
                        <minutes>25</minutes>
                        <seconds>59</seconds>
                    </date>
                    <userid>ihcmdm</userid>
                    <type>S</type>
                    <location type="old">
                        <repository>out</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <location type="new">
                        <repository>site</repository>
                        <slot>0</slot>
                    </location>
                    <container>0001.kit.000049</container>
                    <date type="movedate">
                        <year>2011</year>
                        <month>04</month>
                        <day>22</day>
                        <dayname>Friday</dayname>
                    </date>
                </history>
            </volume>
            ...
```

My C# code:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> caseIdLeavingVault =
    from volume in root.Descendants("volume")
    where
        (from type in volume.Descendants("type")
         where type.Value == "A"
         select type).Any() &&
        (from locationOld in volume.Descendants("location")
         where
             ((String)locationOld.Attribute("type") == "old" &&
              (String)locationOld.Element("repository") == "vault") &&
             (from locationNew in volume.Descendants("location")
              where
                  ((String)locationNew.Attribute("type") == "new" &&
                   (String)locationNew.Element("repository") == "out")
              select locationNew).Any()
         select locationOld).Any()
    select volume.Element("id");

    ...

foreach (XElement volume in caseIdLeavingVault)
{
    Console.WriteLine(volume.Value.ToString());
}
```

Thanks.

---

OK guys, I'm stumped again.  Given this same situation and @Elian's solution below (which works great), I need the `"optime"` and `"movedate"` dates for the `history` used to select the `id`. Does that make sense? I was hoping to end with something like this:

```
select new { 
    id = volume.Element("id").Value, 

    // this is from "optime"
    opYear = <whaterver>("year").Value, 
    opMonth = <whatever>("month").Value, 
    opDay = <whatever>("day").Value, 

    // this is from "movedate"
    mvYear = <whaterver>("year").Value, 
    mvMonth = <whatever>("month").Value, 
    mvDay = <whatever>("day").Value 
}
```

I have tried so many different combinations, but the `Attribute`s for `<date type="optime">` and `<date type="movedate">` keep getting in my way and I can't seem to get what I want.

---

OK.  I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489433/linq-to-xml-query-to-select-specific-sub-element-based-on-additional-criteria) that works well:

```
select new {
    caseId = volume.Element("id").Value,

    // this is from "optime"
    opYear = volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "optime").First().Element("year").Value,
    opMonth = volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "optime").First().Element("month").Value,
    opDay = volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "optime").First().Element("day").Value,

    // this is from "movedate"
    mvYear = volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "movedate").First().Element("year").Value,
    mvMonth = volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "movedate").First().Element("month").Value,
    mvDay = volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "movedate").First().Element("day").Value
};
```

However, it does fail when it finds an `id` with no `"movedate"`.  A few of these exist, so now I am working on that.

---

Well, late yesterday afternoon I finally figured out the solution I had been wanting:

```
var caseIdLeavingSite =
    from volume in root.Descendants("volume")
    where volume.Elements("history").Any(
        h => h.Element("type").Value == "A" &&
        h.Elements("location").Any(l => l.Attribute("type").Value == "old" && ((l.Element("repository").Value == "site") ||
                                                                               (l.Element("repository").Value == "init"))) &&
        h.Elements("location").Any(l => l.Attribute("type").Value == "new" && l.Element("repository").Value == "toVault")
        )
    select new {
        caseId = volume.Element("id").Value,
        opYear = volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "optime").First().Element("year").Value,
        opMonth = volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "optime").First().Element("month").Value,
        opDay = volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "optime").First().Element("day").Value,
        mvYear = (volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "movedate").Any() == true) ? 
                 (volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "movedate").First().Element("year").Value) : "0",
        mvMonth = (volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "movedate").Any() == true) ? 
                  (volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "movedate").First().Element("month").Value) : "0",
        mvDay = (volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "movedate").Any() == true) ? 
                (volume.Descendants("date").Where(t => t.Attribute("type").Value == "movedate").First().Element("day").Value) : "0"
   };
```

This satisfies the requirements that @Elian helped with and grabs the additional date info necessary.  It also accounts for those few instances when there is no element for `"movedate"` by using the ternary operator `?:`.

Now, if anyone knows how to make this more efficient, I'm still interested.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> caseIdLeavingVault =
    from volume in document.Descendants("volume")
    where volume.Elements("history").Any(
        h => h.Element("type").Value == "A" &&
            h.Elements("location").Any(l => l.Attribute("type").Value == "old" && l.Element("repository").Value == "vault") &&
            h.Elements("location").Any(l => l.Attribute("type").Value == "new" && l.Element("repository").Value == "out")
        )
    select volume.Element("id");
```

Your code independently checks if a volume has a `<history>` element of type `A` and a (not necessarily the same) `<history>` element which has the required `<location>` elements.

The code above checks if there exists a `<history>` element that is both of type `A` and contains the required `<location>` elements.

**Update:** Abatishchev suggested a solution that uses an xpath query instead of LINQ to XML, but his query is too simple and doesn't return exactly what you asked for. The following xpath query will do the trick, but it's also a little bit longer:

```
data/customer/mediatype/volume[history[type = 'A' and location[@type = 'old' and repository = 'vault'] and location[@type = 'new' and repository = 'out']]]/id
```

Comment: @Elian Given this same scenario and your solution, how would I select the `id` as well as the `year`, `month`, and `day` of the same volume?  I have tried many combinations, but the `<date type="optime">` or `<date type="movedate">` always get in my way.  I need both for tracking purposes.

Comment: @meffordm: Given a `<volume>` element, which date do you want?

Comment: @Elian I need the `"optime"` and `"movedate"` dates for the `history` used to select the `id`. Does that make sense? I was hoping to end with something like this: `select new { id = volume.Element("id").Value, year = <whaterver>("year").Value, month = <whatever>("month").value, day = <whatever>("day").Value }`  I have tried so many different combinations, but I can't seem to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

What for do you use such complex and expensive LINQ to XML query when you can use simple XPath query:

```
using System.Xml;

string xml = @"...";
string xpath = "data/customer/mediatype/volume/history/type[text()='A']/../location[@type='old' or @type='new']/../../id";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml); // or use Load(path);

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText); // 000049
}
```

---

or if you don't need XML DOM model:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

XPathDocument doc = null;
using (var stream = new StringReader(xml))
{
    doc = new XPathDocument(stream); // specify just path to file if you have such one
}
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator nodes = (XPathNodeIterator)nav.Evaluate(xpath);
foreach (XPathNavigator node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
}
```

Comment: Your xpath query doesn't do the same thing, although I guess you are right that an xpath query will be shorter in this case.

Comment: @Elian: Probably, it doesn't, I'm not so good in XPath, but I just shown the idea in general.

Comment: @Elian: I updated my quest but it still be incorrect, you beat me. Great!

Comment: @Gabe: You're right, OP's task is definitely complex and I didn't understand it correctly, anyway Elian created the correct one much faster then me.

Comment: @abatishchev: :-) It's cool to see that the structure of both the xpath and the linq query is exactly the same. Linq is more verbose, but has the obvious benefit that the semantics is more clear. You have to know the implicit conversion of a non-empty nodeset to `true` to understand the xpath query.

Comment: @Elian @Gabe @abatishchev Thanks for the quick response.  I've always seen good info on stackoverflow and I'm glad I joined it.  BTW, I know the whole thing is hard to understand, especially why I would do it.  But, the XML is output from a third party DB that I have no control over, and I'm tasked with creating a reporting app that will notify our users if the transactions the DB is tracking went as planned...daily.  Fun stuff!